# Bit map of yes/no answers: Should I store it as binary, blob, varchar, or int?

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I am developing a web app in Laravel where I have to ask users a set of Yes/No questions and save the answers in the database. I thought that I should try and save all answers in binary rather than saving them one-by-one since the number of questions vary from time to time. Say in three questions, the user answered Y-Y-N; that would convert into "110".
Now, on the database side, should I:

- save the data as is (varchar)
- use binary/blob
- convert to int and save sa int

Not sure which option is the best, considering that the system sometimes output 50 questions.
MySQL -V info:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.62, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One bit per answer**

If you are willing to limit the number of questions to 64, then `BIGINT UNSIGNED` will work somewhat easily, but limited to 64 true/false values.  Let's say `q` is the column being used.

```
q & 1<<0    -- the bit for question 1 (assuming question numbers start at 1)
q & 1<<22   -- the bit for question 23
(q & 1<<22)  = 0   "false" for q23
(q & 1<<22) != 0   "true"  for q23
(q & 0x7FF)  = 0x7ff   "true" for all of q 1-11
```

Etc.

The `SET` datatype is implemented similarly but is clumsier to use for your case since it wants you to name each bit.

If you need more than 64, then `BINARY` and `BLOB` would let you have up to 4 billion bits (in `LONGBLOB`), but it is much messier to extract a single bit from them.

`INT UNSIGNED` has only 32 bits (4 bytes), thereby not satisfying your "50".

**One byte per answer**

It is probably not unreasonable to have the answers in rows -- a table with (student, question_number, answer).  In this case `answer` could be any of these.  Each takes 1 byte and is about as easy to work on as any other.

```
CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET ASCII NOT NULL.  -- and insert "T"/"F" (or whatever)
TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL   -- 0=false, 1=true
ENUM("F", "T") NOT NULL
```

Comment: thanks. didn't know the limit of int in bytes until now. Also, thanks for the sample php code.

Comment: @NasayaoHarold - Oops, a typo.  4 bytes (32) bits in `INT`.  BIGINT is 8 bytes (64 bits).